Is there any LSF API to automatically populate a submit struct from a resource requirement string consumable by lsf_submit API
I am using LSF API lsb_submit from LSBLIB to submit jobs to LSF cluster from my application. I am looking for an LSF API that can parse a resource requirement string and populate the struct submit object passed as argument to lsb_submit. Is there any other way we can use the resource requirement string directly to submit jobs on LSF cluster using the LSF APIs?
How to call lsb_submit that works like the following bsub command:
bsub -n 24 -R "order[slots] span[block=4]" <prog_name>
The resource string can be more complex, specifying gpu resource, host type, memory resource, etc.
